# One way binding on input not working with object

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to bind the value of an object property to an inpout field like:

```
<input type="number" :value="inputData[index][attribute].value" :name="`expense_voucher[line_items_attributes][${index}][${inputData[index][attribute].attribute}]`" ...
```

Binding just `:value="testval"` with `const testval = ref(555)` is working just fine.
Printing the property also works and is giving the correct value.

```
<p>Value: {{ inputData[index][attribute].value }}</p>
```

Also binding the placeholder is working as expected. Just the value property is not.

`inputData` is an object stored in a Vuex state and provided by a computed property:

```
var inputData = computed(() => {
    return cloneDeep(store.getters['expense/getInitForm'])
});
```

Comment: Give a link to sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was with the specified `type="number"`. Chaning this to `text` fixed the problem. Maybe the prepared data from the backend didn't match the type.